# iOS Dropbox SDK: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox, core-api

My code, in which I'm uploading a file to Dropbox, used to work properly. I could make a connection and had no problems whatsoever, but it seems like it's not able to make the connection anymore and I'm getting 
    "Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The operation couldn’t be completed."

This is the line where the error seems to be occurring:

```
        [self.restClient uploadFile:filename toPath:destDir withParentRev:nil fromPath:localPath];
```

I've been using the example given on the Dropbox Core API website as main reference, so most stuff comes directly from their example, and am therefore not sure what the problem could be.

EDIT: I'm also getting the following: 
    "File upload failed with error: Error Domain=dropbox.com Code=401"